# Xcode stack-trace with atos & dwarfdump

Tags: ios, xcode, stack-trace

I have a problem with my app.
I have a only part backtrace but no crash log, example:

```
"SAMPLE>-[__NSCFConstantString imagePath]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x456eb8
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x33c26c8b objc_exception_throw + 38
36 MyAPP 0x000c5df7 MyAPP + 118263
37 libdyld.dylib 0x341b2aaf <redacted> + 2"
```

Tell me please how to find in code line number with error? 
I have only memory-address: **0x000c5df7**...
Can use commands: atos or dwarfdump or another.

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

The address `0x000c5df7` will result in the symbol `main (main.m:14)` which doesn't help you.

You have a memory issue that you send the `imagePath` message to an object that doesn't understand it since it is of `NSString` class. So search in your code where you are using `imagePath` and then check how that object can be of class type `NSString` instead of another class that understands `imagePath`.

Comment: thanks *Kerni*, but I find answer how to calculate for developers where in his code mistake having only one address **0x000c5df7** (not two, without address Binary Images).

Comment: this is not possible, you'll get false results. You need the load address from the binary images section to get correct symbols for a memory address.